# db_or() returns a SelectQuery-object

Tags: database

In my module, I was trying to make use of db_or() in this way...

```
$filterSparten = db_select($this->tbl_hat_sparte, 'hs')
  ->fields('hs', array('hat_AID'));

$or = db_or();

foreach($_GET['tags'] as $tag) {
  $or->condition('hat_KID', $tag);
 }

 $filterSparten->condition($or)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
```

...which, unfortunately, only returns a SelectQuery-object:

```
SelectQuery Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [hat_AID] => Array
                (...
```

Why doesn't my code return a fetched results-object? I have compared it several times with the examples on the Drupal-pages, but I can't help myself with it.

Comment: No, I was not asking **how** to use db_or, but **why** it returns a SelectQuery-object, not a results-object?!

Comment: where you put this code? and when you try it wihout `db_or` is it return correctly?

Comment: What are you dumping here, exactly? You seem to never save what you fetch to any variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an unchanged core codebase, and assuming you mean that your *final* line is returning a `SelectQuery` (not the `db_or()`, which returns a `DatabaseCondition`), the only way you could be seeing a `SelectQuery` is if you're inspecting the wrong variable, i.e. `$filterSparten`. The query will remain a query, you need to assign the *results* to something else:

```
$results = $filterSparten->condition($or)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
```

Inspecting `$results` should give you what you're expecting.

Comment: This actually solved it, great thx...  :)